# How to prepare a VHD for Jenkins Azure VM Agents plugin

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-automation, jenkins-agent, vhd

I have installed Azure VM Agents plugin.

I want to use a customized VM image as source. (VM with Visual studio and some other tools installed).

There is an option in "Image Configuration" to use "Custom Image URI".

How can I prepare a vhd from a well provisioned/Configured VM in Azure to be used as "Custom Image URL" in this case.

Comment: A fix for this has been released - please see my updated answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49364152/896559)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I prepare a vhd from a well provisioned/Configured VM in Azure
>   to be used as "Custom Image URL" in this case.

Based on my knowledge, you should create a **unmanaged disk** VM then prepare that VM, then you will find the prepare VHD in your storage account, and you will find the URL for that VHD.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a fix for this in progress and awaiting a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-vm-agents-plugin/pull/104).

**Update**

The fix has been implemented and released in *Version 0.7.0, 2018-04-09*. (See the [Changelog](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-vm-agents#AzureVMAgentsplugin-Changelog))

There is now an option to select a Custom Managed Image, into which you can put the Resource ID of your custom image.

[image]